# Mybatis insert function can not return model id

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, mybatis

I used Mybatis. I have Class Form (id, name). I want to insert a new record in the database and get it's Id.

my code is

```
Form form = new Form();
form.setName("insertid");
formMapper.insert(form);
Long id = form.getId();
System.out.println("----" + id);
```

but form.getId() is null.
how to fix it? Thanks.

I have inquired a lot of information, but no one else was in the same situation

Comment: try this `form = formMapper.insert(form);`

Comment: @kr_Li This [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-retrieve-the-value-of-an-auto-generated-key) should be sufficient. If it still does not work, please add 1) DB/driver version and 2) the mapper statement definition (Java method and/or XML) to the question.